# Google place autocomplete- get location name and address in two different field

Tags: javascript, angular, google-places-api

Suppose, I have two fields, Location Name and Location Address. Now, If I type Sydney Opera House in the field location name and select an address from dropdown then **Sydney Opera House** should appear in location name and Location Address should be autocompleted with the address- **Bennelong Point, Sydney NSW 2000, Australia** 
I can get the location name from the full address, but not quite sure how to show the rest of the address in the Location Address field. Here is my code: [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/nAzJtpUjaFC4q3pCSDok?p=preview)

I have a directive named `place-autocomplete.directive`, where in place changed listener I am doing this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.autocomplete, 'place_changed', ()=> {
      input.value=input.value.split(',')[0]; //this is location name
      var inputAdd=input.value.split(',')[1];// the address, how should I pass this?
      var place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      this.invokeEvent(place);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either bind the input type (Venue Address) to [this.address]

Or can set the value of that field like below

```
    getAddress(place: Object) {
       this.address = place['formatted_address'];
       document.getElementById('<id of the Venue Address text box>').value=this.address;
     }
```